# Validate textfield and add warning-text right to textbox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a warning-text right to my textfield when the name is not valid. I have the code for the validation but i can't make some text appear when it input is invalid.

HTML-code:

```
<label for="fname">Firstname:</label> 
<input type="text" name="Firstname:" id="fname" size="40" />
```

Javascript-code:

```
fname.onchange = function() {
    var fn = /^[a-z\s]{2,30}$/i;
    if(!(fn.test(fname.value))) {
        //Insert text right to the textbox here!

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QgMvh/4/)

You can create a span to hold the text you want to display, then insert it after the textbox.  You do this by inserting the new span *before* the textbox's `nextSibling`

```
this.parentNode.insertBefore(warningSpan, this.nextSibling);
```

And if there *is* no `nextSibling`, then `insertBefore` will be smart enough to insert it after the textbox:

Full code:

```
var fname  = document.getElementById("fname");
fname.onchange = function() {
    var fn = /^[a-z\s]{2,30}$/i;
    if(!(fn.test(fname.value))) {
        //Insert text right to the textbox here!

        var warningSpan = document.createElement("span");
        warningSpan.className = "redTextClass";
        warningSpan.innerHTML = "Please enter a value";
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(warningSpan, this.nextSibling);
    } else {
        //no validation error, so we better remove it:
        var next = this.nextSibling;
        if (next && next.className === "redTextClass")
           this.parentNode.removeChild(next);
    }
}
```

Comment: much better than writing to text input itself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i just cant get the star in the right position, now it's in the end of the whole form, not after the individual inputfield.

Also, i can't get rid of the star when the field is validated.

Javascriptcode:

```
fnamn.onchange = function() {
            var fn = /^[a-zåäö\s]{2,30}$/i;
            if(!(fn.test(fnamn.value))) {
                var warningDiv = document.createElement("div");
                warningDiv.className = "star";

                var Astar = "*";
                var star = document.createTextNode(Astar);
                warningDiv.appendChild(star);

                fnamn.parentNode.insertBefore(warningDiv, this.fnamn);

            } else {
                var next = this.nextSibling;
                if (next && next.className === "star")
                this.parentNode.removeChild(next);
            }
        }
```